# For some reason the SVG does not update and render the markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am making a SVG with [snapsvg](http://snapsvg.io/) and generating a path with

```
paper.path("M" + e.pageX + " " + e.pageY + "L20 20");
```

I have a hover event and the class "selected" gets added to the path

.selected class references this marker

```
<defs>
    <marker id="knob" viewbox="0 0 10 10" refx="0" refy="5" markerunits="strokeWidth"    markerwidth="4" markerheight="3" orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z"></path>
    </marker>
</defs>
```

I am linking the markers to the class like this

```
<style> 
   .selected{
      stroke: #006600; 
      marker-mid:url(#knob); 
      marker-end:url(#knob); 
      marker-start:url(#knob); 
      fill: #00cc00; 
    }
</style>
```

For some reason the SVG does not update and render the markers. However when I copy the SVG from the the page and paste it back in the page using chrome developer tools it updates and shows the markers.

Does any one know why it would be doing this?

I have made a JSFiddle of with a snippet of random crap I was making http://jsfiddle.net/XTD4x/

If you click in the Result window it will start drawing a line. Click to add nodes. double click to stop drawing. hover to add the class selected

Comment: How do you create the marker elements? Could possibly be a namespace issue. Can you e.g. create a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I have made a JSFiddle of with a snippet of random crap I was making http://jsfiddle.net/XTD4x/

If you click in the Result window it will start drawing a line. Click to add nodes. double click to stop drawing. hover to add the class selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you put the `<marker>` element (and, strictly speaking, the `<style>` element as well) in the wrong namespace.  It needs to go into the SVG namespace, but jQuery's functions like `.prepend()` put it into the HTML namespace (as they rely on `.innerHTML`, I guess).  Therefore, use either DOM methods like `.createElementNS()`, or use `DOMParser`, like

```
$("svg defs").prepend(
  (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><style type="text/css"> .selected{  stroke: #006600; marker-mid:url(#knob); marker-end:url(#knob); marker-start:url(#knob); fill: #00cc00; }</style><marker id="knob" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3" orient="auto"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" /></marker></svg>', 
    "image/svg+xml"
  ).documentElement.childNodes
);
```

Notice I wrapped the elements into a complete SVG document so that I can parse it.

[Try the modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zp55v/).

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks. I dont think I would have arrived at the solution myself.
Although maybe snapsvg marker functions would have solved the problem. They are just not very well documented.

Answer (score 2):

Second answer: Define the marker outside the SVG generated by snapsvg and put the CSS in an external stylesheet or another `<style>` element outside the snapsvg SVG. No JavaScript required for this, no need to parse and insert anything.

[See another fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Sy4XS/)

Comment: This also works, However in my case the first solution is better